# Why does uniquelist=false option of biblatex package work only if it is inserted at the first time?

Tags: biblatex, package-options

With biblatex package I was using these options: `\usepackage[style=authoryearcomp,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}`
but later I needed to add the `uniquelist=false` option. However the latter did not work, latex ignored it. I solved the problem manually deleting the .bbl file from the working folder and recompiling the document with all the biblatex options. Is it the right procedure? Is there another way to achive this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be easier to help you if you added [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are doing. Without some code that produces the problem we have to guess what you are doing which makes it almost impossible to help. A MWE should be a minimal piece of code that compiles and demonstrates the problem,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `uniquelist=false,` should work as advertised no matter when you add it to your document, **but** since the option affects calculations done by Biber (the backend) it may not show an immediate effect when you only run LaTeX after you added the option. **When you change options that affect Biber, you should rerun the full LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX compilation cycle to be sure that the new settings are used.**

Unlike in some other cases, `biblatex` does not automatically warn you that you have to rerun Biber in order to be sure the option change has taken effect. In theory it would be possible to implement a check for this in `biblatex` and Biber, but it would not be completely trivial either and so far no one has asked for it. If you think that an automatic warning would be useful you can always open a feature request at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

From your description it sounds as if you only ran LaTeX after you added the option. When you deleted the `.bbl` file you (or your editor) had to rerun Biber and at that point the option finally took effect.

I'm guessing that you are using an editor or some other tool that normally runs Biber for you automatically. Presumably that tool did not manage to detect that a Biber rerun was necessary. That's not too surprising since `biblatex` does not warn you about this. However, some tools have extremely advanced heuristics and can already detect situations like this and rerun Biber for you (the wonderful [`latexmk`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) comes to mind). If you are not using such an advanced tool, the only thing you can do at the moment is to make sure to rerun LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX manually. (You certainly don't have to delete the `.bbl` file for that, your editor should offer you an option to do that manually, but if that is the easiest way to get the full rerun, why not?)

Comment: Thanks for your useful explanation!